# Django-Python decimal number formatting comma issue

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I have a model and there is this decimal field rule;

```
product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I am getting data from an xml file and most of the product prices are like this format;

> 847.54

So there is actual number after that for the separator from the remainder there is '.' (dot) for it and this is ok.

However some product prices are like this;

> 2,906.69

The actual number includes an extra comma and this causes a problem. I am getting this error;

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'2,906.69' value must be a decimal number."]
```

Should I change my model? or is there any other solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try replacing the comma and then converting the string to float before inserting into DB.

**Ex:**

```
def cleanDecimal(value):
    return float(value.replace(",", ""))

product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[cleanDecimal])
```

Ex:

```
print(float("2,906.69".replace(",", "")))
2906.69
```